powershell m365 user import doesn't work because of userprincipalname
Please check de picture below. Why it keep giving this error?
enter image description here
I tried different variables:
$_.UserPrincipalName
$UPN

Perhaps you have a extra trailing whitespace after ```New-Msol-User ````

Better stop using those horrible backticks on cmdlets that take a lot of parameters and start using splatting to avoid invisible whitespace errors. Also, check the imported csv file if there are whitespace characters in the headers. And for next time, please do not use (link to) an image but instead, enter the code, the error message and an example of the csv as formatted text
